# Method that can be accessed by multiple threads

Tags: c#, multithreading

I want to write a method to open (or create if it does not exist) a file from different threads.
What would be the `FileAccess` and `FileShare` flags in this case? I tried both FileAccess.Read/Write  and FileShare.Read/Write but don't see any differences. I used the following code to test, looks fine but not sure about the flags (last 2).
Can anybody clarify should I use `FileAccess.ReadWrite` or `FileAccess.Read` and `FileShare.ReadWrite` or `FileShare.Read`?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task first = Task.Run(() => AccessFile());
        Task second = Task.Run(() => AccessFile());
        Task third = Task.Run(() => AccessFile());
        Task fourth = Task.Run(() => AccessFile());

        Task.WaitAll(first, second, third, fourth);

        Task[] tasks = new Task[100];
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            tasks[i] = Task.Run(() => AccessFile());
        }
        Task.WaitAll(tasks);
    }
    public static void AccessFile()
    {
        string path = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        // FileShare.Write gives access violation
        using (FileStream fs = File.Open(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        {
            byte[] by = new byte[100];
            fs.Read(by, 0, 100);
            Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(by));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you think will happen when 2 threads try to write to the same file at the same time? You code is inherently not thread safe.

Comment: Add locker in AccessFile, so only one thread can write in the file in one time, and your function can be called from any thread.

Comment: You are right, I know what you mean.  This is test method where I am trying to understand the last 2 parameters in this scenario. This method will only read no write option for this method.

Answer (score 0):

If multiple threads need to write to the file then you need an [`exclusive lock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx) on it. If you could have some threads read and others write to the file you could use a [`ReaderWriterLockSlim`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim(v=vs.110).aspx).

The `FileShare` parameter is used to indicate how other threads/processes can access the file while a handle is being opened in the current thread. `ReadWrite` means that other threads will be able to read and write from this file which obviously means that if you try to write to the file from the current handle you will probably corrupt the contents.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are only reading you should specify just that (`FileAccess.Read`). And you are OK with others reading so say that (`FileShare.Read`).

And here's nicer test code:

```
ParallelEnumerable.Range(0, 100000).ForAll(_ => AccessFile());
```